# AXIS2/C: wrong element type or null node (om_element.c)

Tags: c, axis, axis2c

Have been searching on google/various other sites for some time now...

**Synopsis:
Unable to serialize/deserialize object, wrong element type or null node (om_element.c).**

**Generated code**:

```
xsi_type_attri = axiom_attribute_create (env, "type", "LocomotiveInformationTransaction", xsi_ns);
//The following line results in ERROR:
axiom_element_add_attribute (parent_element, env, xsi_type_attri, parent);
```

**The error** (from wlis.log)

```
[error] om_element.c(283) Wrong element type or null node
```

**Part of the wsdl file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-Created by TIBCO WSDL->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.nscorp.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.nscorp.com" xmlns:ns1="java:com.nscorp.wlis.locoinfo" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://www.nscorp.com">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.nscorp.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:import namespace="java:com.nscorp.wlis.locoinfo"/>
<xs:element name="UpdateLocoStatus" nillable="true" type="ns1:LocomotiveInformationTransaction"/>
<xs:element name="UpdateLocoStatusResponse" nillable="true" type="ns1:LocomotiveResponse"/>
<xs:element name="isAliveResponse" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:stns="java:com.nscorp.wlis.locoinfo" xmlns="java:com.nscorp.wlis.locoinfo" targetNamespace="java:com.nscorp.wlis.locoinfo" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfCondition">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Condition" nillable="true" type="stns:Condition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The only thing I could see that stood out was the namespace it was
   using. In this case, it looked like (after stepping through the code
   and lots of debugging log statements) it was using the default "xsi"
   namespace. Tried hard coding "ns1" as the namespace for
   LocomotiveInformationTransaction but that did not resolve the issue.

Please let me know if you need additional info.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `parent_element` you given is not `AXIOM_ELEMENT` or has no bound element to it.

This condition is true during element checking:

```
if (!axiom_node_get_data_element(element_node, env) ||
    axiom_node_get_node_type(element_node, env) != AXIOM_ELEMENT)
```

This could be in case you pass other node type (text, node etc..) as `parent_element`.

Check your `parent_element` before `axiom_element_add_attribute` call:

1. call `axiom_node_get_data_element(parent_element, env)` to check if data element is bound. It must be not `NULL`;
2. call to `axiom_node_get_node_type(parent_element, env)` check element's type. It must be `AXIOM_ELEMENT`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I will take a look at that today.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean check `parent` (not `parent_element`), right?
Something doesn't add up here.

**type def**:
`axiom_node_t *parent` and `axiom_element_t *parent_element`

**the following** **call**:
`axiom_element_add_attribute (parent_element, env, xsi_type_attri, parent);`

***which is*** `axiom_element_add_attribute(
    axiom_element_t * om_element,
    const axutil_env_t * env,
    axiom_attribute_t * attribute,
    axiom_node_t * element_node){...}`

within that function:
`axiom_element_find_namespace(om_element, env, element_node,...);` **gets** **called**.

the following is checking the `element_node` which is an **`AXIOM_DATA_SOURCE`** (not `AXIOM_ELEMENT`):

`if(!axiom_node_get_data_element(element_node, env) || axiom_node_get_node_type(element_node,
        env) != AXIOM_ELEMENT)`

`parent` is an `AXIOM_DATA_SOURCE`, could this be something in the `wsdl` file? But what? The same `wsdl` file was working fine with `gSOAP`.

thoughts?